# Random values from list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get some random 5 or 8 values from the following type of input in python

```
[(1, (0.0, 1.1)), (2, (0.0, 2.21)), (3, (0.0, 3.31)), (5, (0.0, 4.41)), 
(5,(0.0, 5.51)), (6, (0.0, 6.62)), (7, (0.0, 7.72)), (8, (0.04, 0.0)), 
(9, (0.04, 1.1)), (10, (0.04, 2.21)), (11, (0.04, 2.21)), (12, (0.04, 3.31)), 
(13, (0.04, 3.31)), (14, (0.04, 4.41))]
```

How can i approach to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert your list of tuples to a dictionary:

```
l = [(1, (0.0, 1.1)), (2, (0.0, 2.21)), (3, (0.0, 3.31)), (5, (0.0, 4.41)), 
(5,(0.0, 5.51)), (6, (0.0, 6.62)), (7, (0.0, 7.72)), (8, (0.04, 0.0)), 
(9, (0.04, 1.1)), (10, (0.04, 2.21)), (11, (0.04, 2.21)), (12, (0.04, 3.31)), 
(13, (0.04, 3.31)), (14, (0.04, 4.41))]

d = dict(l)
```

To get 8 random keys use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random
randomkeys = random.sample(d.keys(), 8)
```

To get the corresponding values you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
import operator
randomvalues = operator.itemgetter(*randomkeys)(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, as several commenters mentioned, the input you posted on your question is a `list` of `tuples`, not a `dict`. That aside, to take a random value from a collection you can use: [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) or [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) from the python standard library.

You can call the functions like so:

```
import random
your_input = [(1, (0.0, 1.1)), (2, (0.0, 2.21)), (3, (0.0, 3.31)),
              (5, (0.0, 4.41)), (5,(0.0, 5.51)), (6, (0.0, 6.62)),
              (7, (0.0, 7.72)), (8, (0.04, 0.0)), (9, (0.04, 1.1)),
              (10, (0.04, 2.21)), (11, (0.04, 2.21)), (12, (0.04, 3.31)), 
              (13, (0.04, 3.31)), (14, (0.04, 4.41))]

# Let's take one random number
one_choice = random.choice(your_input)

# Let's sample 10 random numbers from the list without replacement
n_samples = random.sample(your_input, k=10)

# Let's take 10 random numbers from the list **with** replacement
n_samples = random.choices(your_input, k=10)
```